# how to append local data frame to global data frame in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create one table from each call of the defined function and append the tables together. But it works when I first call the function and filled table corr_tb with output. But when I call the function again and expect to append the new output to corr_tb. Nothing happens. Table corr_tb does not change. Is that because of the global or local variable issue?

```
corr_tb = pd.DataFrame()

def corr_tbl(df, key, var, with_var):
    #calculate correlation by key
    output = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(key)[[var, with_var]].corr().ix[1::2,var]).reset_index()[key+[var]]

    global corr_tb 
    if corr_tb.empty:
        corr_tb = output
    else:
        corr_tb.append(output)
        #print(output.head()) #result could be print but cannot be appended

#call function
corr_tbl(final, ['key1','key2'], 'var1','Sales')
corr_tbl(final, ['key1','key2'], 'var2','Sales')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.append` method doesn't modify the original object but return a new one, you can assign the new one back to `corr_tb`:

```
def corr_tbl(...)
    # did some calculation here
    if ...:
        # 
    else:
        corr_tb = corr_tb.append(df)        # <<<<<< try modifying this line
```

Comment: thanks, I have revised the code first save to a table called 'tmp' then use "corr_tb = tmp". now it works!

Comment: Great! Glad it works. Just want to point out that instead of modifying a global data frame variable, you can also return output from the function, like `def corr_tbl(...): return output` and then use `pd.concat` to concatenate the outputs from different `var1`, `var2` function runs. This might provide a benefit when you want to parallelize the process.